# Jsoup parse android span class

Tags: android, jsoup

i have this code:

```
<span class="definizione">formula di saluto o di augurio usata nella mattina e, in alcune regioni, fino al calar della sera</span><br></p><span class="aiuto">Ricerca: B06A8C00 - buongiorno<span>
```

I have try whit this but not work:

```
Elements image = doc.select("span[class=definizione]");
                imagen= image.text();
```

Comment: what do you expect to get as a result? do you get an Exception? I can't see the problem with your code other than that you should better use a proper class CSS selector ```span.definizione``` instead of your ```span[class=definizione]```, but this is not a real error.

Comment: i have need this formula di saluto o di augurio usata nella mattina e, in alcune regioni, fino al calar della sera

Comment: works for me. so what is the error you get?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the problem is, but this code works for me:

```
final String html =
        "<span class=\"definizione\">formula di saluto o di augurio "
        + "usata nella mattina e, in alcune regioni, fino al calar "
        + "della sera"
        + "</span>"
        + "<br></p>"
        + "<span class=\"aiuto\">Ricerca: B06A8C00 - buongiorno<span>";

final Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

final Elements image = doc.select("span.definizione");
System.out.println( image.text() );
```

This results in the following output:

```
formula di saluto o di augurio usata nella mattina e, in alcune regioni, fino al calar della sera
```

Comment: i have need this formula di saluto o di augurio usata nella mattina e, in alcune regioni, fino al calar della sera

Comment: So what the hell is the problem. you need the string that you get. So all is good now? if so, don't forget to up-vote and accept the answer to signal that your problem is solved.